# Kivy : Weird behavior of a listview

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

The listview works fine for this app, normally when click on "1" a popup is supposed to show with the message "1", same for "2", "3" ..etc

The list contains : ["1","2","3","4"]

The actual behaviour is different from what I was waiting for .

When I click on "1": 
the popup shows with the message "1" but two times.

When I click on "2" : 
The popup shows with the message "2".

When I repeat clicking on "2":
The popup shows twice with the message "1"

This is the code :

```
class MainLayout(GridLayout):
    listview_modal = ListViewModal()

    def on_enter(self):

        listview_modal = self.listview_modal


        listview_modal.list_view.adapter.selection_mode = 'single'

        listview_modal.list_view.adapter.allow_empty_selection = False


        listview_modal.list_view.adapter.data = ["1","2","3","4"]
        self.add_widget(listview_modal)

        listview_modal.list_view.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.callback)
        #listview_modal.list_view.adapter.selection = listview_modal.list_view.selected_item



        button = Button(text='Hello world', font_size='20sp', size_hint= (0.3,0.1) )
        button.bind(on_press=partial(self.popup_display, "Hello world", "\nHello world"

                                    )
                    )
        self.add_widget(button)


    def callback(self, list_adapter, *args):
        if len(list_adapter.selection) == 0:
            title = None
        else: 
            selected_object = list_adapter.selection[0]
            message = " Test message"
            if type(selected_object) is str:
                title = selected_object
            else:
                title = selected_object.text

        self.popup_display(title, message, None)


    def popup_display(self, title, message, widget):
        btnclose = Button(text='Close me', size_hint_y=0.2)
        l = Label(text=message, valign= "middle", halign="center", markup= True)

        l.bind(size=lambda s, w: s.setter('text_size')(s, w))

        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        content.add_widget(l)
        content.add_widget(btnclose)
        popup = Popup(content=content, title=title, size_hint=(.5, .5), auto_dismiss=False)
        btnclose.bind(on_release= popup.dismiss)

        popup.open()




class WabApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return MainLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WabApp().run()
```

And the list class is :

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import lv kivy.uix.listview
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter
#:import fa kivy.factory.Factory

<ListItemButtonTitle@ListItemButton>:
    selected_color:   [24.0, 1.0, 0.39, 0.6]
    deselected_color: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    font_size: 32
    size_hint: .5,.1
    line_height: 1

    #spacing: 100    

<ListViewModal>:
    list_view: list_view_id
    padding: 100
    spacing: 30
    #size_hint_y: None
    ListView:
        id: list_view_id
        size_hint: .98,.98

        adapter:
            la.ListAdapter(data = "",
            cls=fa.ListItemButtonTitle)

""")

class ListViewModal(ModalView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ModalView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Do you have any suggestions for this problem ?

Comment: I had a really similar issue; I sort of doubt it's what you've got, but I was loading an external .kv file manually, using Builder. But my class name and file names were named properly so that it also autoloaded. Try putting the kivy code in a file and let it load implicitly.